# Homeomorphism of graphs in infinite case.

Tags: graph-theory

Sometimes it's still unknown for how to determine **homeomorphism** or **isomorphism** of graph in infinite case.
I have two problem that I don't know how to ask.

1) Consider two graphs $G$ and $H$. The first one is $V(G) = \{0,1,2,3\dots\}$ and $E(G)=\{ (i,i+1)\}_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}}$. The second one is $V(H) = V(G)$ and $E(H) = \{(0,i)\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$

2) Consider the same graph $G$ and $M$, such as $V(G)=V(M)$ and $E(M) = E(G)/(1,2) \cup (0,2)$

Now we want to know if graphs are homeomorphic or not ?

I guess in first case the question is **no**. Their plane picture looks like *line* and infinite *star*. So we can't make even a isomorphism between them.

For a second part I have a doubt. They have so much in common, but this erasing of edge make me believe that make some sense. However there are subgraphs that $M' \cong G$ and $G' \cong M$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In question 1: the fact that the graphs look different does not prove that they are not isomorphic. Sometimes there are very surprising nontrivial isomorphisms between mathematical objects. These graphs really are not isomorphic, and one proof of this fact is that one graph has a vertex of infinite degree and the ither does not.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, the graphs are isomorphic.  The isomorphism exchanges $0$ and $1$ and leaves all other points fixed.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for this. What about first case ?

Comment: In the first case, you're correct.  Obviously, an isomorphism has to preserve vertex degrees, so there's no possible candidate in $G$ to map to $0$ in $H$.